# Is Guid.ToString( ) also unique

Tags: c#-4.0, guid

In C#, we know that `Guid` data is unique for a given machine. Will `Guid.toString( )` also be unique for a given machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well `Guid.ToString()` represents all the data within a `Guid` - so if there are two non-equal `Guid` values, calling `ToString()` on each of them will give two non-equal strings too. Is that what you wanted to know?

Comment: Yes. Thanks. I couldn't find this even though I googled like crazy before posting this question.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, GUIDs *should* be unique in time and space ... not just for a given machine.

And yes, the textual representation of a GUID is every bit as unique as the GUID itself :)

If a GUID is unique, then myGuid.ToString() is also unique.  Of course :)

Answer (score 1):

`Guid.NewGuid()` will be unique per machine, yes. `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()` is still unique, just a  `string` typed version of the GUID generated.